# Windows Phone Develop error Error "Csc.exe" exited with code -1073741819

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

I'm running a windows phone 8.0 project in visual studio and recently started running into this error when trying to compile the project after a reboot.
Error   1   "Csc.exe" exited with code -1073741819.

has anyone seen this error before?

Sometimes it builds fine even with the error, and sometimes it wont.

Comment: "-1073741819" = "0xC0000005" = access violation.

Answer (score 2):

This was happening to me after I updated my computer on windows 8.  I fixed it by going to control panel > programs > found my instance of visual studio 2012 and repaired it.